How can I mock a FirebaseAuth such that every FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser gets the mocked user
I'm facing an issue while writing unit tests for my ProfileScreenViewModel class in Android using Kotlin and MockK. The ProfileScreenViewModel class initializes a property called user using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser. When attempting to mock FirebaseAuth.getInstance() in my test setup, I encounter a MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock.
Here's the relevant code snippet from my ProfileScreenViewModel class:
// Inside ProfileScreenViewModel
private val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

And here's the setup code for my test class:
// Inside ProfileScreenViewModelTest
@Before
fun setUp() {
    // Mock FirebaseAuth
    val mockFirebaseAuth = mockk<FirebaseAuth>()
    val mockFirebaseUser = mockk<FirebaseUser>()
    every { mockFirebaseAuth.currentUser } returns mockFirebaseUser
    every { FirebaseAuth.getInstance() } returns mockFirebaseAuth
    
    // Mock other dependencies
    mockRepository = mockk()
    mockTimeProvider = mockk()
    
    // Initialize ViewModel with mocks
    viewModel = ProfileScreenViewModel(mockRepository, mockTimeProvider)
}

I expect FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser to be properly mocked and return the mocked FirebaseUser instance. However, I'm encountering the MockKException mentioned above (on the line every { FirebaseAUth.getInstance() } returns mockFirebaseAuth).
Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly mock FirebaseAuth.getInstance() in my test setup using MockK? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried only mocking the current user, but then the user in the ProfileScreenViewModel class is null. I really do not want to pass the user in the constructor mockTimeProvider.

I have found the solution! Just adding the mockkStatic(FirebaseAuth::class) after mocking a FirebaseAuth object was enough to mockk correctly. Hope this helps somebody in the future!

If you found an answer that solved your problem, it's best to add it as an answer. In this way, you'll prevent the question from being deleted in the future.
